# What is the meaning of the tilde in some debian openjdk package version string?

Tags: debian, version, deb

Reading the [changelog](http://metadata.ftp-master.debian.org/changelogs/main/o/openjdk-8/unstable_changelog) of the [debian openjdk-8 source package](https://packages.qa.debian.org/o/openjdk-8.html) we see that there is a version called **openjdk-8 (8u45-b14-4)** and the next one is **openjdk-8 (8u60~b22-1)**.

What is the meaning of the tilde in this last version?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The official reference for the Debian package version format is in the [Debian Policy Manual](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-controlfields.html#s-f-Version). The format is designed to allow “reasonable-looking” version numbers with a well-defined (if somewhat complex) comparison relation to decide when a version is more recent than another.

For the most part, the comparison is a lexicographic comparison of the string. For example, `1foo` is sorted before `1ga`. However, sequences of digits are compared in numerical order, so `foo10bar` is sorted after `foo9bar`.

With a lexicographic order, a string is always sorted before its prefix. The tilde character allows a deviation from that: `foo~bar` is always sorted before `foo` as well as before any version that begins with `foo` followed by a character other than `~`. This is often used for beta versions: `8u60~b22` is sorted before `8u60`. I don't know why the OpenJDK 8 packages seem to alternate between `-b` and `~b` suffixes though.

Tilde suffixes are also used for backports of all kinds. For example, if the same version of a package is present in both Debian stable and testing, and a security fix needs to enter stable, then the package in stable will have a suffix like `-2~deb1` while the version in testing (compiled against more recent libraries) will have `-2`; that way the package is an upgrade to the `-1` version, but if a system is upgraded from stable to testing, the `-2~deb1` stable version will be upgraded to the `-2` testing version. Official backports use `~bpoNUMBER` for the same purpose, this way a `4.2~bpo7` version will be upgraded to `4.2` if that ever appears in the main distribution.

Comment: Ok for the meaning, but, in this case, what is the reason of the tilde?

Comment: @OrtomalaLokni I guess they needed a character that wasn't usually present in version numbers (so punctuation, and not `.` or `-` or `+`), that wasn't a shell special character (in most circumstances), and that was allowed in Windows file names, and that was vaguely space-like in appearance.

Comment: It's not just used for backports, but also for things like release candidates: 1.0~rc1-1 < 1.0-1 -- this can be used for an upload to experimental